# Error in PostScript listing taken from an old 1987 magazine

Tags: postscript

Magazine scan is here:
https://archive.org/details/verbum103unse/page/16

I used OCR and a manual pass to get the text as it is:
https://gist.github.com/gingerbeardman/79d6df2ab08033a37f5eb23162fa6a4c

I am fairly confident that I have removed any OCR errors in the file, and I have parsed it using this command:

`$ gs -sDEVICE=nullpage -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH verbum-1-3.ps`

The error I get is in the second definition:

```
{inHard Disk:Logos:Coarse} 
{ps} 
gsave
63 -63 translate
/ang -30 def
45
  { Icosahedron 72 ang cos mul 72 ang sin mul 24 FaceNos
    Dodecahedron -72 ang cos mul -72 ang sin mul 24 FaceNos 
    6 12 translate 1.03 dup scale /ang ang 24 add store 
    /ax ax 12 add store /ay ay 4 add store /az az 1 add store
  } repeat
grestore
```

**Error:**

> /undefined in Icosahedron

But at this point my PostScript experience from half a lifetime ago is exhausted. What am I missing?

Any pointers or help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks as if the code is incomplete and is missing the *Icosahedron* and *Dodecahedron* subroutines.

Answer (score 1):

I found some more OCR errors:

```
10c10
<   { Vertex face 3 get get a load pop TurnXYZ pop moveto 
---
>   { Vertex face 3 get get aload pop TurnXYZ pop moveto 
12c12
<       {Vertex face 3 -1 roll get get aload pop TurnXYZ popline lineto}
---
>       {Vertex face 3 -1 roll get get aload pop TurnXYZ pop lineto}
15c15
<   /angcos x px mul y mul z pz mul add add size psize mul sqrt div def 
---
>   /angcos x px mul y py mul z pz mul add add size psize mul sqrt div def 
18c18
<     dup 0 1t {pop 0} if 
---
>     dup 0 lt {pop 0} if 
54c54
< /lim 0. 000001 def 
---
> /lim 0.000001 def 
59c59
< 297 423 translate 0.84 dup scale -306 -336 translate 75 2 -1 atan {pop} setscreen 0.8 setgray 
---
> 297 423 translate 0.84 dup scale -306 -396 translate 75 2 -1 atan {pop} setscreen 0.8 setgray
```

But I wasn't able to get it to run.  (My naive guess is it's related to the `setscreen` call.)  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I have a hunch the missing functions will be in a book published by the same people. I've ordered a copy.